# Error in the suggested edits review queue

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

For some time now I've had problems with rejecting suggested edits in the suggested edits review queue. Usually the majority of edits is actually an improvement but when the exceptions occur the system won't let me reject those and instead displays a generic error message: "An error has occured".

Now I don't know if this is a problem in the system or with my browser. Did someone else experience this? If so, I'd be grateful on tips how to fix it if it is related to the browser/settings/similar. I'm using Firefox.

Comment: This has been happening to me too. I can only reject if I enter a custom comment. What browser are you using? (I use Firefox.)

Comment: @gung oh yea sorry, I should have said that. I'm also using Firefox.

Comment: I have run into the same problem repeatedly (Firefox also), so mods are not immune.

Comment: This problem still persists (Firefox). Almost always I have to add a comment when rejecting edits.